# Simple AJAX bookmark

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a list of items on a page using PHP.  I want to add a simple AJAX toggle to allow users to bookmark an item in the list while they are browsing.

So if the item->bookmark field = 1, then the item is bookmarked and it should show a simple image.  When they click it again, it make it ="0" in mysql and the bookmark image changes back to something else.

What is the best way to do this without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is the way to go to save data on the server. But if you want to add / remove bookmark on the fly while on the page, you can use a function that toggle bookmark on and off, using data-* attributes

```
$(".bookmarkButton").click(function(){
if(! $(this).parent().data('bookmark')){
    alert('bookmarked');
    $(this).parent().data('bookmark', 1);
    // Add image + AJAX call
}
else {
    alert('not bookmarked');
    $(this).parent().data('bookmark', null);
    // Remove image + AJAX call
}
```

});

Here's a simple JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YwTuB/

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you could have googled "jquery ajax example" but here you go...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" id="<?php echo $whateverYourIdIs; ?>">Bookmark me!</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item', $('.container')).click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "some.php",
          data: { id: id }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });
});
```